# Picking phone or email from contact list in android

Tags: android

In an android project i had this intent to pick a phone number from my contact list

```
        btnContacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Open Contacts
            Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
        }
    });
```

and this to get the result

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    insertedPhoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    formatContact(insertedPhoneNumber, name);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do the same operation but if the contact dindt had phone number i would retrive the email instead.

Comment: check this for answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/42250015/6497550

Comment: check my post for the answer it will answer all your questions
http://stackoverflow.com/q/42250015/6497550

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there is a way to do the same operation but if the contact dindt had phone number i would retrive the email instead.

No. You ask for phone numbers you get phone numbers. If you need additional logic or `if`s, then you need to code it yourself.

Comment: yes, my question was if i could ask for both phone or email(if contact dindt had phone number).

Comment: [Get only email address from contact list Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10117750/1235698)